# Error "CKEditor" is undefined for IE users

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

In one of our projects users get an error "CKEditor is undefined" from time to time if they working with IE for quite some time and than load an XPage with the CKEditor. The error occurs direct after loading the page before the user can interact with it.

It looks like there might be a problem with caching. With a fresh start of IE the problems goes away.

CKEditor is an object to access the CKEditor on the page. So I guess the browser try to call a method but the object has not been loaded yet.

Has anybody experienced the same problem? Maybe also a solution?

Comment: check please the log.nsf, perhaps the entries could help us.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this in XPages and I'm trying to remember how (and where) we resolved it.

Comment: Actually there are no entries in the log.nsf. It seams that all needed files are delivered, but they don't arrive in time.